# Is it possible to return the return from a lambda when using Api gateway with eventbridge?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have created a micro service architecture

Api gateway -> Eventbridge -> Lambda

The trouble is that although the execution is fine and the lambdas run as expected the return received by the user or app is the eventbridge response. I can’t find any docs on how eventbridge handles responses for http requests through API gateway.

I already read the docs, but i only get with Api gateway -> Lambda, hope someone can help me, if i can return the response from the lambda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its **not possible**. You have to save the result of a lambda function in DynamoDB for example, and then have a separate Api gateway call to fetch the results to the end user.